# Error: Could not find or load main class MakePhoneCall Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MakePhoneCall

Tags: java, intellij-idea, twilio

I am following the Twilio tutorial"How to Make Outbound Calls"  Located at this URL: [Twilio MakePhoneCall](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-java)  I've copied the code to my InteliJ  and then run the program.
I get the following error:[Error Code and Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3kP6.jpg)

Thanks for your assistance in this matter.

Comment: Did you attached Twilio jar to the project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing Twillo jar attached to your project.

Try downloading it from [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/7.1.0) and attach to your project classpath.

Comment: Hi again I'm a newb......I added the twilio jar file as shown in my link to jpg file but now have a main class problem:https://videos-billcory.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/twilio/cant-load-main-class.jpg

Comment: Your Java file and Class name should be the same. So rename your info.java file to MakePhoneCall.java